# Magento 2: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closest' of undefined

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs

I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closest' of undefined

Here is my code:

```
var _self = this;
            var btn = _self.element;

    var parentBlock = _self.element.closest('.new-shipping-address-form').find('form.form');
     var input = parentBlock.find('input[aria-required=true]');
```

Can you please check my code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that **_self.element** is undefined, you should debug it to see what **element** refers to and see if you can fix it